# In R, how to group data by multiple columns in the descending order, then give every group an index starting from 1?

Tags: r, sorting, indexing, group-by

My data is like:

```
a <- data.frame(a1=c(2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3),
                a2=c(5,4,2,2,5,5,6,6),
               a3=c(3,1,5,5,7,7,8,8))
```

Then, i sort the data like:

```
aa <- a %>% 
  arrange(desc(a3),desc(a2),desc(a1))
```

The data looks like:

```
> aa
  a1 a2 a3
1  3  6  8
2  3  6  8
3  2  5  7
4  2  5  7
5  1  2  5
6  1  2  5
7  2  5  3
8  2  4  1
```

Now i need to group the data by a3, a2 and a1. So, in aa, the rows 1 and 2 will be in one group, and row 3 and 4 will be in one group as well. Now I need to give every group an index, which starts from 1. So, the data should look like below:

```
> aa
  a1 a2 a3   Index
1  3  6  8    1
2  3  6  8    1
3  2  5  7    2
4  2  5  7    2
5  1  2  5    3
6  1  2  5    3
7  2  5  3    4
8  2  4  1    5
```

So in summarizing, I need to arrange the data in the descending order first, then group it, then give every group an index starting from 1. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could potentially use `group_indices`, but that would also have a reordering issue.  Instead, an option is to `paste` (or `str_c` - from `stringr`) on the columns of interest and then `match` with `unique` values of pasted string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
aa %>%
   mutate(Index = str_c(a1, a2, a3), 
          Index = match(Index, unique(Index)))
```

---

Or instead of `arrange`ing separately, use it with `across`

```
library(tidyr)
a %>% 
   arrange(across(a1:a3, desc)) %>% 
   unite(Index, everything(), remove = FALSE) %>% 
   mutate(Index = match(Index, unique(Index)))
```

---

Or with `.GRP` in `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
setDT(aa)[, Index := .GRP, .(a1, a2, a3)]
aa
#   a1 a2 a3 Index
#1:  3  6  8     1
#2:  3  6  8     1
#3:  2  5  7     2
#4:  2  5  7     2
#5:  1  2  5     3
#6:  1  2  5     3
#7:  2  5  3     4
#8:  2  4  1     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
a_ordered <- with(a, a[rev(order(a1, a2, a3)), ])
a_ordered$idx <- with(a_ordered,
                      cumsum(abs(c(
                        0,
                        diff(as.integer(factor(paste0(
                          a1, a2, a3
                        ))))
                      ))) + 1)
```

Data:

```
a <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  a2 = c(5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6),
  a3 = c(3, 1, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8)
)
```